# Extend functionality of dependent classes in a module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a library that hast several classes. Some are used inside others because `Sentence` consists of lots of `Token`.

Now I need to add a new property to `Token` and a new method to `Sentence` that takes the new property of `Token` into account.

```
class Sentence:
    tokens: List[Token] = []

    def to_tokenized_text(self):
        return ' '.join(self.tokens)

    def to_original_text(self):
        out = ''
        for token in self.tokens:
            out += token
            if token.space_after is True:
                 out += ' '
        return out
```

To add a new method I would usually just subclass the `Sentence` class and add it there

```
class MySentence(Sentence):
    def to_my_text(self):
         out = ''
         for token in self.tokens:
             if token.skip:  # example of new property
                 continue
             out += token
         return out
```

This would work if there would be no need for the new property of `Token`. But I cant Subclass `Token`, because `Sentence` would still use the original `Token` class and I don't want to overwrite the whole class or all of the methods that include the use of `Token`.

I found a way to overwrite a property getter in [this unrelated GitHub Issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/85#issuecomment-917134257), but i could not translate it to my situation.

In the end i would like to be able to call either `Sentence.to_my_text()` or `MySentence.to_my_text()` and have the Tokens concatenated respecting the value of the new property (e.g. `skip`), that is not available in the original `Token` class.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Sentence.to_my_text`?

Comment: Either `Sentence.to_my_text()` if its possible to extend the original class, or MySentence.to_my_text() if its the better approach to use subclassing.

Comment: Subclassing is the better approach. But if you subclass, then perhaps there's no need to define a *new* method, just override `to_original_text`.

Comment: the `to_original_text` needs to stay in tact, because it will be used as well. It's just another way to display the content. But anyway, this is just the minor issue. The major one is the additional property on the `Token`, wich can not be solved by subclassing.

Comment: Sure it can. An instance of `MySentence` is entirely independent of an instance of `Sentence`. As long as you don't try to create an instance of `MySentence` using an old-style `Token`, you'll be fine. The question is, how *are* you creating instances of `MySentence`?

Comment: `Sentence`, or in case case of subclassing `MySentence`, is the first Instance you create with a `string`. The class itself then, calls a tokenization, that fills the `Token` List. The tokenization is an inherited part of the original `Sentence` class and therefore i have no control over the `Token` class used.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works and its indeed inspired by the unrelated GitHub Issue.

I've added

```
def get_my_new_prop(token):
    try:
        return token._my_new_prop
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def set_my_new_prop(token, val):
    token._my_new_prop = val


Token.anonym = property(lambda self: get_my_new_prop(self),
                        lambda self, val: set_my_new_prop(self, val))

class MySentence(Sentence):
    # ...
    
    def to_my_text(self):
        # ...
        for t in self.tokens:
            if t.my_new_prop:
                apply_magic_dust(t.text)
        # ...
```

and now the `Token`s have a new property i can read and write.
The new Method can make use of it and apply things based on that new property.

I had to catch the `AttributeError` for the cases where the property was never set on a `Token`.

One flaw I found, my IDE does not recognize the new property at the `t.my_new_prop` position.